# How can I include form value in url_for function from jinja template?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I want to pass the selected `{{ exam[0] }}` to the `show_exam_form` function.
However I could not do that.

Environment

```
Python 3.6.1
Flask==0.12.2
Jinja2==2.9.6
```

app.py

```
@app.route('/exam/<int:exam_id>', methods=['POST'])
def show_exam_form(exam_id):
    print(exam_id)
```

html

```
<form action="{{ url_for('show_exam_form', exam_id=exam_id) }}" method='POST'>
  <select name=exam_id>
    {% for exam in exams %}
    <option value="{{exam[0]}}">{{exam[1]}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
```

How can I solve it?
Please let me know if you need more information to solve it.
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

Requesting the id as parameter is not necessary. Here is an example how to handle this selected value for future OPs.

In `app.py`:

```
@app.route('/exam', methods=['GET','POST'])
def show_exam_form():
    exams = {
        "IT-101":"IT Fundamentals",
        "IT-201": "Object Oriented Programming",
        "IT-301": "Database Management",
        "IT-401": "Operating Systems"
    }
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template('so.html', exams = exams)
    else:
        exam_id = request.form["exam_id"]
        flash(exam_id)
        return render_template('so.html', exams = exams)
```

In `so.html` template (in my case it extends a base templete):

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <form action="{{ url_for('show_exam_form') }}" class="form" method='POST'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select name="exam_id" class="form-control">
                {% for key,value in exams.items() %}
                    <option value="{{ key }}">{{ value }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Output:

[image: Input Form]
Figure 1: Input Form

[image]
Figure 2: Flashing the selected value

Comment: Yeah! I noticed that it is not necessary after post. But you give me the great example. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I do not need to send the exam_id from jinja to Flask.
Just send via POST and get it with request.form['exam_id'] in the `show_exam_form` function.